# Integer is not inserted into the MySQL database Error

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP script that is supposed to save data from a select function in a database. I did the whole thing with the switch case function. The data should actually be saved, but for an incomprehensible reason, this does not happen. My script looks like this:

```
 if(isset($_POST['acc_type'])){
  $select = $_POST['acc_type'];
  switch ($select) {
   case '2':
    $sql = "INSERT INTO userdata (accounttype) VALUES (2)";
    break;
   case '3':
    $sql = "INSERT INTO userdata (accounttype) VALUES (3)";
    break;
   default:
    $sql = "INSERT INTO userdata (accounttype) VALUES (1)";
    echo "nothing";
    break;
   }
 }
```

I have already tested whether it is due to the input (by setting an `echo`). But this was done. Therefore it must be due to the transfer to the database.

There should be 3 choices that are important for my login. The data should be saved as 1, 2 or 3 (depending on what is specified).

Comment: I don't see where the query `$sql` is executed. Do you?

Comment: The whole thing lies in an If statement. It is related to many other unimportant things. It is executed as soon as a submit button is clicked. I don't want to add the full script now because it is irrelevant.

Comment: try the query in your databse direkt and post the complete error message and also show us the create table of userdata

Comment: The command works weirdly in the database.

Comment: Debug print the value of $sql, right before you call the mysqli_query() function. Check the return value from the mysqli_query() function. What did you find out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you don't need this repetitive stuff.

```
$select = ($_POST['acc_type'] == 2 || $_POST['acc_type'] == 3) ? $_POST['acc_type'] : 1;
$sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO userdata (accounttype) VALUES (%d)", $select);
```

A better solution would be to prepare the statement properly, but I don't know how you plan to execute your query (you didn't provide any code). If that's all, you actually don't insert anything in your database, you just set the query to a variable.

Comment: Okay thanks I will change it. Nevertheless, it should actually work if I didn't do something wrong myself. I have another INSERT INTO which is marked with the same variable. It is directly under this function. This works perfectly. Maybe I did something wrong there. If so, please clarify. Do not know me well yet: D

Comment: I have now removed the variable but it still does not work. Maybe someone has an answer?

Comment: Then provide please some more code, there is no more context to answer with... Thanks.